# C# GridView FindControl HTML unordered list

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html-lists, findcontrol

I want to find an `unordered list` inside my `GridView` so that I can hide it based on a condition. I do not know what to cast the object as however. Using `HtmlGenericControl` does not seem to work. I receive a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGV" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="myCb" runat="server" Text='Hi'/>
                <ul id="myUnorderedList" runat="server" Visible="True">
                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="myTb" runat="server" Width="300" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C#:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in myGV.Rows)
{
    if (Some Condition)
    {
        //works bc properly casted to CheckBox
        ((CheckBox) row.FindControl("myCb")).Visible = false; 

        //Does not work. What to cast this to?
        ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) row.FindControl("myUnorderedList")).Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl** is a correct cast for **ul**.

Besides, you do not even need to cast to **HtmlGenericControl**, because **Visible** is a property of **System.Web.UI.Control** from which all web controls inherited.

You just need the following code -

```
(row.FindControl("myUnorderedList")).Visible = false;
```